# Why can't you operate packs on HIGH during take-off, approach and landing on a 737-800?

Tags: landing, takeoff, boeing-737, approach, bleed-air

It's in the FCOM Limitations Chapter and I think that these phases are critical phases of flight and I don't want to reduce my engine performance by purposely creating a high demand for bleed air from my compressors.

Just want to seek some inputs on whether my chain of thought makes sense.

Comment: Yes that is about it.  Bleeds can impart a significant performance penalty because of energy losses from the bleed that limit thrust.  Not posting as an answer because I don't have 737-specific information.

Comment: alrighty thank you sir, it makes good sense and further more, if i leave my wing anti-ice on for takeoff, once it lifts off the ground, the air-ground switch sensor will shut the anti-ice.